# What could be causing this error in HackerRank?

Tags: python

So in one of the challenges in HackerRank, I wrote a program to calculate the weekday on a particular date. The code works perfectly fine when I type it into different editors (IntelliJ IDEA, online-python) but I get this error when I run it in HackerRank:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    08 05 2015
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's my code:

```
from calendar import day_name, weekday

month, day, year = map(int, input().split())
print(day_name[weekday(year, month, day)].upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

HackerRank is evidently still using Python 2, a version of Python that has been discontinued for years now. Back on the days of old, you need to use `raw_input`, not `input`, to get a line of text from the user. In Python 2, you need

```
month, day, year = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Though, of course, the real answer is to find a programming challenge that uses software written in the past decade.

**Edit:** As indicated by shriakhilc's comment, you should be able to select Python 3 in HackerRank, which I highly recommend. Python 2 hit end-of-life in mid 2020.

Comment: HackerRank provides a drop-down with various Python versions. At the time of writing there is Pypy2, Pypy3, Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found it, and it's working as expected now.